# C# WPF changing symbol (Segoe MDL2 Symbols) on Button when clicking on it

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm totally new to C# and WPF. I have backgroundmusic in my program, which I want to mute / unmute via a button "Button_Mute". It works fine.

Now I've added a symbol using the FontFamily Segoe MDL2 which I also deliver with my application. Still fine.

The symbol should change when I click on the button, but it just shows hieroglyphics.

Here you can find a table with all the symbols.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/jj841126.aspx

Now what I have tried so far:

App.xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="Forms" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="pack://application:,,,/Assets/#Segoe MDL2 Assets"/>                            
</Style>
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
 <Button x:Name="Button_Mute" Style="{DynamicResource Forms}" Content="&#xE767;"/>
```

Symbol is getting showed, everything's fine.

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
private void Button_Mute_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (buttoncounty == 1)
        {

            MediaElement_Song.Volume = 0;                
            Button_Mute.Content = "&#xE74F;";
        }

        if (buttoncounty == 2)
        {
            MediaElement_Song.Volume = 1;
            Button_Mute.Content = "&#xE767;";

        }
        buttoncounty++;

        if (buttoncounty == 3) buttoncounty = 1;


    }
```

But this isn't working. The symbol just changes into hieroglyphics.
Help with coding would be highly appreciate! Thank you

Comment: `&#xE74F;` is an XML (and hence XAML) unicode character escape sequence. In C# you'll have to write `\uE74F`.

Comment: Fixed my problem, thanks.